# Where can we find (Lost) ancient Indian text by Buddhist scholars which was Translated in other languages?

Tags: pali-canon, books

Where can we find (Lost) ancient Indian text by Buddhist scholars which was Translated in other languages?

A Lot of Ancient Indian Buddhist text(Which was lost over a period of time with decline of Buddhism in India.) was translated(Probably from Sanskrit and Pali), specially by Tibetan, Chinese, Japanese, Korean, Sri Lankan Scholars. Where can we find these texts(may be translated in English.)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some basic resources for you. Most of these were originally written by Indian scholars and now exist only in Tibetan or Chinese translation, although the BDK America collection also includes texts written by Chinese scholars.

Tibetan texts (translated to English):

- https://read.84000.co/section/LOBBY.html
- https://www.lotsawahouse.org/indian-masters/

Chinese texts (translated to English)

- https://lapislazulitexts.com/tripitaka/
- https://bdkamerica.org/tripitaka-list/

I assume you are only looking for secondary texts, not Buddha's original discourses, but if you are into alternative versions of these, then Sutta Central has a nice collection of non-Pali versions of suttas, mostly Chinese translations from lost Sanskrit or Gandhari originals (with English translations).

- https://suttacentral.net/pitaka/sutta/linked/sa
- https://suttacentral.net/sa-2
- https://suttacentral.net/pitaka/sutta/numbered/ea
- https://suttacentral.net/ma

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll be able to find "lost" texts translated into English. An example of a recently-found text that used to be "lost" is the Gandhari Dhammapada.

This article, https://www.ancient-buddhist-texts.net/Buddhist-Texts/C3-Comparative-Dhammapada/Comparative-Dhammapada.pdf, compares several different Dharmapadas. The Gandhari one is one of them. There is also a translation of it published by Timothy Lenz. This is only one example of such a text. There are far too many to list individually.

Comment: I find the first sentence isn't clear -- it's contradicted by the rest of the answer. Perhaps it's intended to say that there are so many lost texts translated, that you won't find any single list/repository of them.

Comment: It is not contradicted by the rest of the answer. Lost texts are lost. They are not translated. Only recently-found texts that _used to_ be lost can possibly be translated.

Comment: I see. I think the OP clarified that it's asking about texts that were lost to India, and which instead survived as translations, in Tibet etc.

Comment: If that is what they meant, then the list is too large for any poster here to give. Also, the grammar could be adjusted if that is what they meant. For instance, off the top of my head, the Flower Garland, countless minor Prajñāpāramitā sūtras, the EBTs (the Sanskrit EBTs are all fragmentary to differing degrees) the Golden Light Sūtra, the Humane King Sūtra, the Śūrangamasūtra, the prelude and postlude to the Threefold Lotus Sūtra... the list can go on indefinitely.